# Paired and repeated measures! Now what? ANOVA or mixed model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, anova, repeated-measures, paired-data

I have a simple setup. I have 10 patients and I would like to test the effect of a certain drug on kidney function. Each patient will serve as his own control and intervention.

First for the control observations, the baseline left kidney function and right kidney function are measured for each patient.

Then once the intervention is introduced, the left and right kidney function of each patient is measured again.

In order to determine the effect drug, I am looking for significant differences between the intervention and control measures.

[image]

The values in the table above are fictitious and are meant to provide clarity.

I technically have 20 paired observations, however they are not independent. There are two paired observations per patient and these are inherently correlated.

I could take the average of the left and right kidney functions, before and after the intervention. Then I would just have 10 paired observations, and I could carry out a simple paired samples t test.

Is there another way I could find significant differences without averaging or throwing away data? I would like to keep these repeated measures. Is there a way I can take their dependency into account?

I've looked up repeated measure ANOVA, but I'm not sure if that's what I need. Do I need to use a linear mixed effect model?

Note: If I do a paired t test as if they were 20 independent paired observations, my result is statistically significant p<0.02. If I average left and right and use 10 independent paired observations my result is not statistically significant, with p>0.10.

Comment: Just to clarify - the "control" group is the baseline measurements (both kidneys) in the control group (all patients), and the "intervention group" is the post-intervention measurements (both kidneys) in the intervention group. So all patients were measured 4 times: twice at baseline, and twice after the intervention. All patients received the intervention. Is this all correct ?

Comment: @RobertLong Yes that's correct! What kind of ANOVA or model should I be doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically an analysis of change model.

2 measurements on each subject were taken at baseline, and 2 more at follow-up. I will refrain from calling this "control" and "intervention" as that could be somewhat misleading.

We have repeated measures within patients. So we could consider a model that fits random intercepts for patients, to control for this. There are also repeated measures within each kidney of each patient. I would suggest the following model:

```
measure ~ time + LR + (1 | PatientID)
```

In order to fit this model, it is necessary to "reshape" the data as follows:

```
PatientID   time   LR   measure
1          -0.5    L    19    
1          -0.5    R    29
1           0.5    L    27
1           0.5    R    20
2          -0.5    L    14    
2          -0.5    R    13
2           0.5    L    13
2           0.5    R    11
```

The estimate for `time` will answer the research question: What is the change in `measure` associated with the intervention, while controlling for the repeated measures within patients, and within the same kidney's of each patient.

Another approach is to fit nested random effects, and treat `LR` as a random factor:

```
measure ~ time + (1 | PatientID/LR)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert. By reshaping the control/intervention nature of the measurements, the 'time' variable you have made is ordinal, right? But shouldn't it be categorical in nature?

Comment: You're welcome.  When there is only 2 timepoints it won't make any difference.

Comment: I think I should be able to fit a mixed model to either of the approaches you mentioned. Some final questions- is there a a subtype of ANOVA that I could also use to arrive at the same? Also I have never heard of analysis of change, could you point me in the direction of some good litereature?

Comment: "Analysis of change" is just a term used to describe a study where you are interested in an outcome that changes over time, so it's quite common. Googling <"Analysis of change" regression> gives about 52 million results.  Most of the references I know are paywalled, but here is a recent one that isn't (and the other references I know are all referenced therein) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.02764.pdf

Comment: As for ANOVA, if you make time categorical in the above model, you are fitting a repeated measures ANOVA (and the results should be the same)

Comment: In the second approach you mentioned, if I were to construct the null hypothesis model:

`measure ~ (1+PatientID/LR)`

I get a warning  "boundary (singular) fit". Can I ignore this?

Comment: You are missing the time fixed effect

Comment: That would be in the actual model, but if I want to find the p value I need to create the null model without the time effect, correct? That's when I get the error.

Comment: The null model would be a lineear without random effects. However, try not to be too concerned with p values. Specify the model based on domain knowledge, not some arbitrary threshold of a probability of observing the data or data more extreme (if the null hypothesis is true). What will you do if the p value is 0.05000001 ? What if it is 0.04999999 ?

Comment: I understand what you mean. Choosing to accept or reject the null hypothesis based on an arbitrary threshold is not what I intend on doing. But I still need to report the p value with it.

Comment: No, you really don't :) P-values are the devils work.

Comment: Could you explain why the null model is one that is linear without random effects? I want to test the effectiveness of the drug, so it makes sense to me that the null model is the one without the time variable, which would be a model without the fixed effect in this case. That's at least what I learned from here: http://www.bodowinter.com/uploads/1/2/9/3/129362560/bw_lme_tutorial2.pdf

Comment: because a p-value tells you, **if** there is actually **no** effect, what is the probability of observing the data, or data more extreme, than what you observed, and that is, very rarely, the question that you want to answer.  Did you do a sample size calculation before you collected the data ? Also, is the table in the OP your whole dataset ?

Comment: Yes this is the full dataset and a sample size calculation was done. What would the formula of the null/reduced model be then? Or alternatively, should I just report the estimate of the coefficient for the time variable with a CI and call it a day?

Comment: But how did you calculate the sample size if you didn't know what analysis model you were going to use ? Anyway yes I would report the estimate and CI, but I have used your data and I do not get a singular fit with `lmer(measure ~ 1 + (1 | PatientID/LR), data = dt)`

Comment: The original analysis model involved averaging the left and right kidney functions. So a simple paired t test would be used. The sample size calculation was done, with the hopes of finding an effect size of 30%. I am attempting a mixed model to see how much of a difference it would make. The data in the OP is fictitious and randomly generated. With the actual data, I get a singular fit.

Comment: OK, that's fair enough (sample size). For future reference, it is good to let us know you have included fictitious data - then I for one won't bother to input it myself and try to model it :) As for the singular fit, I would guess that the variance component for `PatientID:LR` is at, or close to zero. If so, just remove it and use the first model.

Comment: Oops, actually I did mention it was fictitious data in the OP haha. Sorry, perhaps I should've put it in bold, didn't mean to waste your time! I do appreciate your follow-up comments and help with troubleshooting. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ahh my bad ! Never mind. So I think you just need to use the first model in my answer.

Comment: Worked out well! Out of curiosity, how would I use the aov() function to do the same thing as the first model?

Comment: Gald to hear it. No, `aov` does not account for repeated measures within patients,

Comment: This is an improper way of getting your attention, but would you mind taking a look at a question I had a few days ago? It also has to do with mixed modelling. I would greatly appreciate your input and I'm having trouble getting some traction here.